# Batch file command not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to run this batch file remotely It will kill the IE process's but when I try to open a .lnk file it won't do it. When I go onto that machine, open up the command prompt and type in the command to run the .lnk file it works with no issues.. please help!

Code to remotely execute batch file:

```
psexec -u Administrator -p password -i -d \\hostname "c:\Emergency_POD\test.bat"
```

Code on machine to run: (Only the taskill command works.. not the for command)
cd/

```
taskkill /im iexplore.exe /f 
for %a in ("C:\Emergency_POD\*.lnk") do @start "" "%a"
```

Command to run on cmd (This command works with no issues:

```
for %a in ("C:\Emergency_POD\*.lnk") do @start "" "%a"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be better off with `%%a` in place of `%a` in the batch file.